# Jquery Click Function-get value of clicked tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, return-value, jquery-events

```
<?php
include 'dbc.php';
?>
<?php
$query  =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `editor`");
 $row=mysql_fetch_row($query);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#text").click(function(){
        var alrt =  $(this).text();
        alert(alrt);
        })  ;
    
    
    });//ready function end here
</script>
<span id="text">
<?php echo $row['0']; ?>
</span>
<br />
<br />
<span id="text">
<?php echo $row['1']; ?>
</span>
<br />
<br />
<span id="text">
<?php echo $row['2']; ?>
</span>
```

---

This is one of my sample page and the script, but its not working properly, I'm getting the value of 1st span when its clicked, not the rest,  now the question is, I want to get the value of clicked span, without knowing its id or class.
Please help.

Comment: you cannot have multiple id="test", use classes instead. If you don't want to work with classes, you can select your elements with their tag name. $("span").click( ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the span using jquery selector like this :

```
$('span').click(...
```

Here is your example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span").click(function(){
    var alrt =  $(this).text();
    alert(alrt);
    })  ;
});//ready function end here
</script>
```

Comment: well i fixed it my self and completed the project.. thanks anyway.. :)

Answer (score 1):

`id` must be unique. You should use `class`.

```
<span class="text">
<?php echo $row['0']; ?>
</span>
<br />
<br />
<span class="text">
<?php echo $row['1']; ?>
</span>
```

For the javascript, use `$(".text").click` instead of `#text` to point to the elements of that class.

Comment: i used tags directly, when i'm done my code was something like this.. and its working for me..

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("span,div,h1,h2..........p").click(function(){
    var alrt =  $(this).text();
    alert(alrt);
    })  ;
});//ready function end here
</script>

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML replace `id = "text"` with `class="text"`. Then your jquery would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".text").click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Don't use the same ID for more than 1 element in an HTML page.